# An ordinary differential equation equal to an infinite sum of legendre polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, legendre-polynomials

what is the method for solving a differential equation when a summation is involved from the start ?

ex. what method is required to find a particular solution to

$$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{P_n(x)}{2^n}$$

I should point out also that

$\tfrac{2}{(5-4x)^{1/2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{P_n(x)}{2^n}$.

Edit: $|x| \leq 1$

My attempt :

$\tfrac{2}{(5-4x)^{1/2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{P_n(x)}{2^n} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{2^{n+1}}{(5-4x)^{1/2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)$. ( I don't know if you can do this though.....)

then we assume that $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nP_n(x)=\sum \tfrac{a_n2^{n+1}}{(5-4x)^{1/2}}$

$y'=\sum \tfrac{a_n2^{n+2}}{(5-4x)^{3/2}}$

$y''=\sum \tfrac{3a_n2^{n+3}}{(5-4x)^{5/2}}$

Is this anyway right ?

Comment: Is the left side $((1-x^2)y')'$?

Comment: @Nosrati I think that is a way to express it yes . Its the legendre equation anyway .

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what function you have on the right hand side. Let's call it:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{P_n(x)}{2^n}$$

As @Nosrati correctly noted, you have:

$$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'=((1-x^2)y')'$$

Which immediately allows us to integrate both sides:

$$(1-x^2)y'=\int_a^x f(t) dt$$

Where $a$ is an arbitrary constant, which depends on the intitial conditions. I have written the integral this way to keep track of the different integration variables we are going to have.

Now we assume $x \neq \pm 1$ and find:

$$y(x)=\int_b^x \frac{1}{1-u^2} \int_a^u f(t) dt ~du$$

Where the second constant $b$ also depends on the initial conditions.

Now whatever the definition of $f(x)$ (a series or a closed form), you just need to evaluate the integrals and apply the initial conditions correctly.

Comment: I should have pointed out in my main body that we are also told that $|x| \leq 1$. how does this change the method you suggested. I'm sorry, I thought i had included that information originally

Comment: @exodius, deal with the case $x^2=1$ separately. You can consider this solution valid for $|x|<1$

Comment: your answer springboarded the following work.  

So we have that $((1-x^2)y')'=\sum_{n=1}\tfrac{P_n(x)}{2^n}$.

But by rodriguezes formula we have that $P_n(x)=\tfrac{1}{2^nn!}\tfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$. 

which means that $((1-x^2)y')'=\sum_{n=1}\tfrac{1}{4^nn!}\tfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$

Now we can integrate both sides with respect to x

$$(1-x^2)y'=\int^1_{-1}\sum_{n=1}\tfrac{1}{4^nn!}\tfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n=\sum_{n=1}\tfrac{1}{4^nn!}[\tfrac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^n]^1_{-1}$$

Comment: But obviously the value on the right will be zero for all n. what did you mean by seperating the cases where |x|<1 and $x^2=1$. also in your example how do you know what values to sub in for x,b,a,u . I think that perhaps where i have it here that u=-a must be incorrect as it makes the whole thing equal zero

Comment: @exodius, you are supposed to integrate w.r.t. $t$ and then w.r.t. $u$. That way you get a function of a single variable $x$, as it should be. $a,b$ are constants, determined by the initial conditions. You can treat them as arbitrary parameters, and then after getting the general expression for $y(x)$ you compare it to your initial conditions and solve for $a,b$.

Comment: How do we find what the initial conditions are though , I've scoured my notes and thers no mention of how to do it and i've never had to do it before :/

Comment: @exodius, we don't. They are given as a part of the problem statement. If not, you just leave the constants undefined. That's called the general solution. You are asked for a particular one though, so if any will do, just pick whatever parameters you want

Comment: So if I said that $\Rightarrow y = \sum_{n=1}\tfrac{1}{4^nn!}\int_1^x\tfrac{1}{1-u^2}[\tfrac{d^{n-1}}{du^{n-1}}(u^2-1)^n]du$ is a particular solution would I be done or do I have to solve that awful integral because I've been trying to figure out how to calculate it since my last comment to no avail :/

Comment: @exodius, depends on what whoever have given you the assignment wants... The integral is not that awful, maybe try integration by parts? Also, I would pick $-1$ as the lower limit, or maybe $0$

Comment: @exodius, I looked up the integral and it doesn't seem to have a simple expression. If however, you use the supposed value of the series $\frac{2}{(5-4x)^{1/2}}$, you might have better luck. Have you tried that? $$ $$ I understand that this is Legendre equation, and we have Legendre polynomials on the right, but I'm not sure how to use that

Comment: Thank you for all your help , I had to hand it in because I was out of time unfortunately. But on the bright side it seems to have been a very difficult object to work with that won't (hopefully) play to large a part in the rest of the course.